# Create NetCDF subset with different sizes

Tags: data, netcdf

I have to create a netCDF file with different subsets.
For example subset1 must be a 2d matrix, subset2 a vector, etc.

I am using functions of netcdf library in C/C++ code:

nc_create for the file creation,

nc_def_dim for dimensions definition,

nc_def_var for variable (subsets) definition.

Can you indicate me an example code which creates more variables with several dimensions?

I didn't find it.

Answer (score 1):

For multiple variables, you need multiple nc_def_var() calls.

One way to get example code is to create a CDL-based text file the matches your needs, and then run 'ncgen -c' (http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/docs/netcdf/ncgen.html)  on it to get sample c code.